# How to show a specific screen when the program is opened the first time?

Tags: java

I was wondering how to make the program show a specific text it's ran by the first time, I know in android programming, a way to do this is by making a specification in the manifest. So I hope you'd understand me and can help me.

Comment: Are you trying to show a "screen" or "a specific text"? Is it a GUI app?

Comment: Make file and store a flag such as isfirst use. Initially set the flag true and after first use set the flag false. And use it to show the specific screen you want

Comment: do you mean a splash screen ?

Comment: Yes, it is a GUI app, I want to show a text the first time it's opened but then the idea is to create a table.

Comment: You need a text only for the initial use only,Right.Or you need a splash screen image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create a flag file use this

```
String FLAG_PTH="path/to file/flag.txt"; 
String flag="";
```

> Use this code at load event of the page

```
try{
    byte[] bfr=new byte[50];

    FileInputStream IPS=new FileInputStream(COL_PTH);
    int tn=0;
    int nread=0;

    while((nread=IPS.read(bfr))!=-1){
       String clr=new String(bfr);          
       flag=clr;
     } 
            IPS.close();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fe){
    System.out.println("ERR:9"+fe);
}
catch(IOException IOe){
    System.out.println("ERR:10"+IOe);
}

if(flag=="True"){

 // type your code for showing some text,or whatever it is.


try{

        FileWriter FW=new FileWriter(FLAG_PTH);
        BufferedWriter BF_Wr=new BufferedWriter(FW);
        BF_Wr.write("TRUE");
        BF_Wr.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("ERR:06"+e);
    }
}
else {
     //hide text and go through normal open
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, I would have a text file with the word false in it,right at the top.Then in the programme you read that line, if it reads true then make it display whatever text you wish.After that you delete the file and make a new one(inside the if statement) with the same name only with true at the top this time.Therefore that if statement can only run again if that text file is changed to true.This is going to need buffered streams so read up on that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html .Alsojust a piece of advice keep all of your resources inside your jar file in a source folder as best as you can(its a lot less easier for users to mess with) doing this will cause you to need to use getResourceAsStream : https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yksgU4SxoJY .I assure you it won't take long to go throught this.